# Hölder continuity of $x^{\alpha}$ with $-1 < \alpha < 0$.

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to show Hölder continuity of $x^{\alpha}$ with $-1 < \alpha < 0$ for $x \in (0, 1)$. This means that there exists some $b$ such that the following inequality holds for all $x, y \in (0, 1)$:
$$ \lvert x^{\alpha} - y^{\alpha} \rvert \leq C\lvert x - y \rvert^{b} $$
I can't seem to find the trick.

Comment: And your $b$ should be in which range?

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry, between 0 and 1. I hadn't seen this yet, I just assumed I could take a negative $b$, then it is quite trivially wrong.

Comment: Usually for Hölder continuity we would assume $b>0$. This is not possible for your function. The LHS blows up for fixed $y$ and $x\rightarrow 0^+$. However, the RHS is bounded by $1$.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed, thank you. For the quick response. Stupid of me to waste so much time on not properly checking conditions.

Comment: Happens to all of us. And you will surely remember this condition for a long time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $α$ is negative this is false, since any Hölder continuous function is uniformly bounded on a bounded domain, which is false here.
Just remark that
$$
|y^\alpha-x^\alpha|\underset{y\to 0}\to \infty
$$ 
while for $b\geq 0$
$$
|x-y|^b ≤ 1.
$$